# Java Spring Framework bind variable for IN clause

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I wanted to use bind variable for IN clause, I wanted to make the list configurable using framework.

```
hql+=" and num_string in  (:destNum)";
param.put("destNum",dest_Num);
```

dest_Num is configured as string. I have added the property in config but still its not working. Any one know using bind variable with IN clause where the in values will be passed as a String? Or any other way to implement this.

Comment: are you using hibernate query?

Comment: 1. Why does it not work? 2. What exactly does the string look like? 3. Why not use a list?

Comment: Please add the param variable declaration.

Comment: Query query = getSession().createQuery("Select ioObject from IoObject as ioObject where ioObject.Id in (:IdList)")
        .setParameterList("IdList",IOObjectIdList); .

Comment: I converted the string to list and it works.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

use like this If hibernate use

```
 String hql = "from A where name in (:names)";
Query q = s.createQuery(hql);
q.setParameterList("names", l);
```